# ¿Como llamar datos en csv de fecha y hora que estan dentro de una misma columna, para hacer un ciclo diurno?

Tags: python, datetime, csv, pandas

soy muy nueva en esto! 
Estoy viendo una clase llamada análisis de datos, donde se nos pide realizar un ciclo diurno de una serie de tiempo que mide radiación por minuto, pero tengo un archivo en csv donde en una sola columna tengo la fecha y la hora, como hago para separarlas y luego seleccionar solo la hora de interés.

Espero una pronta respuesta.

Buen día.

Ejemplo 
Data = pd.read_csv("6001_Pira.csv", index_col=0)

```
Fecha_Hora                 Radiacion  Temperatura  Calidad

2016-11-09 21:24:00        103       299.87        1
2016-11-09 21:25:00        105       299.85        1
2016-11-09 21:26:00        108       299.85        1
2016-11-09 21:27:00        110       299.85        1
2016-11-09 21:28:00        114       299.85        1
2016-11-09 21:29:00        117       299.80        1
2016-11-09 21:30:00        120       299.78        1
2016-11-09 21:31:00        121       299.76        1
2016-11-09 21:32:00        121       299.75        1
```

Como es un analisis por minuto, es decir necesito saber como es la radiacion todos los dias a las 21:28:00 pero la hora y la fecha estan en una sola columna, como se puede filtrar los datos pertenecientes a esa hora en especial?

Comment: ¿que has intentado hacer? ¿A que le llamas ciclo diurno?

Comment: Bienvenida a [es.so] Claudia, para poder contestarte adecuadamente hacen falta más datos. Para empezar es imprescindible que pongas un ejemplo de tu csv o como mínimo de la columna donde guardas fecha y hora para ver que formato tiene. Si añades tu código para ver como accedes al csv y como lees la columna también estaria bien. Mirate el [tour](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y [Cómo preguntar](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para ver como funciona este sitio, tal y como está la pregunta sin esos datos puede ser cerrada.Saludos.

Comment: Hola! muchas gracias por el consejo, ya la estoy editando!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero de todo quiero avisar de que mis conocimientos de `Pandas` no son los mejores y que es posible que existan formas más apropiadas de hacer esto.

En principio todos los datos que tienes son cadenas, es decir, si lees de un `csv` todos los datos serán de tipo `str` (string) a no ser que fuerzes la conversión de tipos cuando lees el documento. Como la fecha es de tipo `str` y no de tipo `datetime` lo más simple es buscar la cadena que quieres dentro de la columna `Fecha_Hora`. Para esto puedes usar `.str.contains(subcadena)`:

```
import pandas as pd

Data = pd.read_csv("6001_Pira.csv")
Resultados = Data[Data['Fecha_Hora'].str.contains('21:28:00')]
```

Si forzaras la conversión de tipos al leer tu documento porque necesitaras que las fechas sean de tipo `datetime` para poder, por ejemplo, compararlas adecuadamente, entonces lo anterior no sería válido.

Si los datos de la columna `Fecha_Hora` fueran de tipo `datetime` podemos usar `.dt.time` para extraer solo el tiempo (hora, minutos y segundos pero sin la fecha) de cada fila y filtramos comparandola con la hora deseada:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

dtypes = {'Fecha_Hora':datetime}
parse_dates=['Fecha_Hora']
Data = pd.read_csv("6001_Pira.csv", dtype=dtypes, parse_dates=parse_dates)

diana = datetime.strptime('21:28:00','%H:%M:%S').time()
Resultados = Data[Data['Fecha_Hora'].dt.time == diana])
```

Si se aplica sobre un `csv` como el siguiente (a modo de ejemplo):

```
ID,Fecha_Hora,Radiaccion,Temperatura,Calidad
01,2016-11-09 21:24:00,103,299.87,1
02,2016-11-09 21:25:00,105,299.85,1
03,2016-11-09 21:26:00,108,299.85,1
04,2016-11-09 21:27:00,110,299.85,1
05,2016-11-09 21:28:00,114,299.85,1
06,2016-11-09 21:29:00,117,299.80,1
07,2016-11-09 21:30:00,120,299.78,1
08,2016-11-09 21:31:00,121,299.76,1
09,2016-11-09 21:32:00,121,299.75,1
10,2016-11-10 06:28:00,114,299.85,1
11,2016-11-10 20:28:00,114,299.85,1
12,2016-11-10 21:20:00,114,299.85,1
13,2016-11-10 21:28:00,114,299.85,1
14,2016-11-10 21:28:01,114,299.85,1
```

Los dos códigos nos dan la misma salida cuando imprimimos `Resultados`:

```
    ID           Fecha_Hora  Radiaccion  Temperatura  Calidad
4    5  2016-11-09 21:28:00         114       299.85        1
12  13  2016-11-10 21:28:00         114       299.85        1
```

Que creo que es lo que quieres.

Comment: Hola! el primer ejemplo funcionó super bien! Gracias!

Comment: Hola! el primer ejemplo funcionó super bien! Gracias!                           Fecha_Hora  Radiacion  Temperatura  Calidad
Codigo_Estacion                                                      
6001             2016-03-09 05:01:00         -1       293.15        1
6001             2016-03-10 05:01:00         -2       294.61        1
6001             2016-03-11 05:01:00         -2       293.96        1
Ahora me queda solucionar como graficar! te agradezco mucho mucho!